# How to get a probability distribution over tokens in a huggingface model?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm following [this](https://ramsrigoutham.medium.com/sized-fill-in-the-blank-or-multi-mask-filling-with-roberta-and-huggingface-transformers-58eb9e7fb0c) tutorial on getting predictions over masked words. The reason I'm using this one is because it seems to be working with several masked word simultaneously while other approaches I tried could only take 1 masked word at a time.

The code:

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaForMaskedLM
import torch

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
model = RobertaForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

sentence = "Tom has fully ___ ___ ___ illness."


def get_prediction (sent):
    
    token_ids = tokenizer.encode(sent, return_tensors='pt')
    masked_position = (token_ids.squeeze() == tokenizer.mask_token_id).nonzero()
    masked_pos = [mask.item() for mask in masked_position ]

    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(token_ids)

    last_hidden_state = output[0].squeeze()

    list_of_list =[]
    for index,mask_index in enumerate(masked_pos):
        mask_hidden_state = last_hidden_state[mask_index]
        idx = torch.topk(mask_hidden_state, k=5, dim=0)[1]
        words = [tokenizer.decode(i.item()).strip() for i in idx]
        list_of_list.append(words)
        print ("Mask ",index+1,"Guesses : ",words)
    
    best_guess = ""
    for j in list_of_list:
        best_guess = best_guess+" "+j[0]
        
    return best_guess


print ("Original Sentence: ",sentence)
sentence = sentence.replace("___","<mask>")
print ("Original Sentence replaced with mask: ",sentence)
print ("\n")

predicted_blanks = get_prediction(sentence)
print ("\nBest guess for fill in the blank :::",predicted_blanks)
```

How can I get the probability distribution over the 5 tokens instead of the indices of them? That is, similarly to how [this](https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2021/03/02/easy-masked-language-modeling-with-machine-learning-and-huggingface-transformers/) approach (that I used before but once I change to multiple masked tokens I get an error) gets the score as an output:

```
from transformers import pipeline

# Initialize MLM pipeline
mlm = pipeline('fill-mask')

# Get mask token
mask = mlm.tokenizer.mask_token

# Get result for particular masked phrase
phrase = f'Read the rest of this {mask} to understand things in more detail'
result = mlm(phrase)

# Print result
print(result)

[{
    'sequence': 'Read the rest of this article to understand things in more detail',
    'score': 0.35419148206710815,
    'token': 1566,
    'token_str': ' article'
},...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `last_hidden_state[mask_index]` is the logits for the prediction of the masked token. So to get token probabilities you can use a `softmax` over this, i.e.

```
probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(last_hidden_state[mask_index])
```

You can then get the probabilities of the topk using

```
word_probs = [probs[i] for i in idx]
```

PS I assume you're aware that you should use <mask> rather then ___, i.e. sent = "Tom has fully <mask> <mask> <mask> illness.", I get the following:

> Mask  1 Guesses :  ['recovered', 'returned', 'cleared', 'recover', 'healed']

> [tensor(0.9970), tensor(0.0007), tensor(0.0003), tensor(0.0003), tensor(0.0002)]

> Mask  2 Guesses :  ['from', 'his', 'with', 'to', 'the']

> [tensor(0.5066), tensor(0.2048), tensor(0.0684), tensor(0.0513), tensor(0.0399)]

> Mask  3 Guesses :  ['his', 'the','mental', 'serious', 'this']

> [tensor(0.5152), tensor(0.2371), tensor(0.0407), tensor(0.0257), tensor(0.0199)]