How to make huggingface transformer for translation return n translation inferences?
So I am trying to use this transformer from huggingface https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/tasks/translation. The issue is that I want n translations returned and not just one. How can I  do that? I mean, I want to have ordered translations, that means the translation with index 0 would have the highest confidence, this is important for my use case, which is about translating natural language to commands language (about 40 commands without subcommands).
The github repo and exact model is this one https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/main/t5/models/hf_model.py
This is the HuggingFace API:
translator = pipeline("translation_xx_to_yy", model="my_awesome_opus_books_model")
translator(text)

But I am intending to use the model directly from the google search github repo, so it seems some tweaking should be done here:
predictions = []
    for batch in dataset:
      predicted_tokens = self._model.generate(
          input_ids=self.to_tensor(batch["inputs"]), **generate_kwargs
      )
      predicted_tokens = predicted_tokens.cpu().numpy().tolist()
      predictions.extend(
          [vocabs["targets"].decode(p) for p in predicted_tokens]
      )

    for inp, pred in zip(inputs, predictions):
      logging.info("%s\n  -> %s", inp, pred)

    if output_file is not None:
      utils.write_lines_to_file(predictions, output_file)

Also any suggestion on some other model option to solve this natural language to cmd is welcomed!

Check out the documentation of the generate method: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies#customize-text-generation
The parameter to use is num_return_sequences. But T5 by default does a greedy search, meaning it generates word by word and discards the options on its path there. To generate multiple options you need a selection of alternative paths. There are basically two ways to do this (my guess would be that for your case the first option works better):
If you activate do_sample, the model will not just pick the highest probability token at each time, but instead take a weighted sample from the distribution of next word probabilities.
predicted_tokens = self._model.generate(
          input_ids=self.to_tensor(batch["inputs"]), num_return_sequences=3, do_sample=True, **generate_kwargs
      )

If you set num_beams to anything larger than 1, you switch to beam search, where for each further token the model follows multiple alternatives of next tokens.
predicted_tokens = self._model.generate(
          input_ids=self.to_tensor(batch["inputs"]), num_return_sequences=3, num_beams=4, **generate_kwargs
      )  # note that num_return_sequences has to be smaller or equal to num_beans

To also get the scores of generated outputs you can additionally use the arguments output_scores=True and return_dict_in_generate=True, although you should note that these will return the logits of all individual tokens, which you then would have to put together to the overall probability yourself, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/75029986/18189622.
In general, T5 might not be the best model for code synthesis, as of my knowledge it wasn't pretrained or fine-tuned on it in its Multi-Task Instruction Fine-Tuning. There is however FLAN-T5, which was fine-tuned on a wider range of tasks, including Code Synthesis. There are also CodeT5 and many other models relating to code synthesis.

for some reason, I am witnessing there is a lot of work done on CodeT5 contrary to FLAN-T5, do you have an idea why? If you filter by most recent https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=text2text-generation&sort=modified&search=code

I think FLAN-T5 is more of a niche model that did not get the attention that the original T5 did, so I guess many people just use T5 as a base to fine-tune their own variants and put them online. This popularity shows that it generally seems to work to use T5 as a basis for fine-tuning. But I still think other models might provide a better basis for this task because they have been pre-trained using code-related tasks and should therefore pick up tasks more efficiently in a new fine-tuning, especially if you have only a small training set.

thanks, so you'd suggest FLAN-T5 is something to pick, what are those "other models" to you?

I was thinking of fine tunning codeT5, which was pre-trained on code generation tasks, and I was thinking also to add another language layer for summary.

check out the compute_transition_scores https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.26.1/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationMixin.compute_transition_scores

I personally never fine-tuned a model for code synthesis, so I can't really give you any insight for which models work well, but one thing I would try is to fine-tune any of the recent open-source instruction-focused LLMs, but then fine-tuning their base variant instead of the instruction one, e.g. mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.3 or meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B. But CodeT5 and FLAN-T5 might reach similar performances while being much smaller and easier to handle.

The compute_transition_scores seems very convenient, I did not know that one, thanks!
